# Unable to select item from pop up list view in MVC 4

Tags: c#, css, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC application in which we are providing pop-up in which user list gets populated and this pop up will have select button dynamically created and calling function selectitem('cellvalue i.e. userid').
in Function selectitem we call controller method

```
 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Methodname","Master")',{ userid : id },
        function (usredata)
      {
        //processing of user data
      }
    );
```

Controller method look like this

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult Methodname(int userid)
   {
   }
```

But my problem is when I am selecting any record from pop up user list then it stucks there. Values not get filled in the parent screen. I observed it in debug mode that when we click on select button then it gives following error

GET http://ipaddress:8091/Master/Methodname?userid=2 500 (Internal Server Error)

Please let me know what could be reason or what could be the alternative to resolve this.

Comment: I can see this error in browser debug mode.

Comment: Does it hit the controller method while selecting any record from pop up ?

Comment: 500 means that there is an exception error in your server side code. Debug your MVC controller action.

Comment: Internal server error means that your `Methodname() method is throwing an exception. Debug it!

Comment: I have debuged it but unable to get any exception anywhere. Other observation would be bit strange that I have different environments prod and testing. In testing environment the same code is running fine. Is there any issue related to .Net updates?

Comment: This does not hit any controller method while selecting any records

Comment: I am calling function as below                                                                               '<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="selectItem(' + cellvalue + ')" />' but function selectItem unable to call